# Instagram api changes

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am making a website to provide auto-likes/follows for Instagram. I'm concerned that I will not be approved by Instagram's review process. I am connecting to Instagram with a valid access token and following all the rules however I am not sure if I fall into a valid use case for their review - https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/

If this is no longer allowed does it mean companies like boostgram are finished?

Can anyone advise please?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a recent hackathon I've been too one of the team tried to make the same thing, they have encountered problems with the API (Instagram actively blocked this type of usage). After they realized they would have problems using the API they decided to use selenium.

Answer (score 0):

they, i.e boostgram, etc. develop it without official instagram API, they used private API that uses instagram mobile application. I developed instagram bot, I have it on my local server.